# Where is the python code for the methods used for zipline?

Tags: python, zipline

I'm quite a beginner to Python but in java, you normally have these imports showing exactly where the objects are coming from. For example, the import statement below tells me the SpringBootApplication object comes directly from the Spring Boot class and I can dive into the class to read all its method code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

Now I'm looking at the zipline library in python:

https://github.com/quantopian/zipline

This is from their sample code on the main page of their github repo:

```
from zipline.api import (
    history,
    order_target,
    record,
    symbol,
)
```

So I have  a look at the zipline folder to see whether there is an api file from which the methods `history, order_target, record, symbol` is imported as I want to read the underlying code that is driving these methods.

The code doesn't tell me much (https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/blob/master/zipline/api.py):

```
from .finance.asset_restrictions import (
    Restriction,
    StaticRestrictions,
    HistoricalRestrictions,
    RESTRICTION_STATES,
)
from .finance import commission, execution, slippage, cancel_policy
from .finance.cancel_policy import (
    NeverCancel,
    EODCancel
)
from .finance.slippage import (
    FixedSlippage,
    VolumeShareSlippage,
)
from .utils import math_utils, events
from .utils.events import (
    date_rules,
    time_rules
)

__all__ = [
    'EODCancel',
    'FixedSlippage',
    'NeverCancel',
    'VolumeShareSlippage',
    'Restriction',
    'StaticRestrictions',
    'HistoricalRestrictions',
    'RESTRICTION_STATES',
    'cancel_policy',
    'commission',
    'date_rules',
    'events',
    'execution',
    'math_utils',
    'slippage',
    'time_rules'
]
```

However, there is a file called `api.pyi` that seems to contain some text on what the methods I'm interested in does (https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/blob/master/zipline/api.pyi). For example, with the method `record`, it says:

```
def record(*args, **kwargs):
    """Track and record values each day.

    Parameters
    ----------
    **kwargs
        The names and values to record.

    Notes
    -----
    These values will appear in the performance packets and the performance
    dataframe passed to ``analyze`` and returned from
    :func:`~zipline.run_algorithm`.
    """
```

I thought maybe the code was sitting within `zipline.run_algorithm` and also had a look for the `zipline/run_algorithm` file but couldn't find it in the repo.

Where is the code saved for these methods in python? I just want to read the code to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: I have a little experience working with Java. In Python you could inspect objects and determine their locations,  so for instance, if you import a module: `import test` then `test.__file__` will give you the directory of which the module `test` exists. Same for packages and all other objects, all have a corresponding builtin attributes that would give some information of some sort about that object, `dir(object)` returns many details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipline` is using a somewhat complex and unusual import structure.  The clue is in this comment in `api.py`:

```
# Note that part of the API is implemented in TradingAlgorithm as
# methods (e.g. order). These are added to this namespace via the
# decorator ``api_method`` inside of algorithm.py.
```

If you look in `algorithm.py` you can see these `record` and the rest of these methods defined with the `@api_method` decorator.  (And if you look in `zipline/utils/api_support.py` you can see the code for the decorator itself, which adds these methods to `zipline.api` by using `setattr`.)